# Run commands Android Terminal Emulator. Install apk by code

Tags: android, installation, apk, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to run commands on the Android Terminal Emulator. I have my device rooted and I installed *superuser.apk*.

I'm doing it like this:

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while ( line != null ) {
            Log.i("SHELL", line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And also well:

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<b>cmd</b>*);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch ( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm trying to install a. Apk by code. I tried the following:

**cmd** => `pm install /mnt/sdcard/app.apk`
Without any results.

**cmd** => `su -c "pm install /mnt/sdcard/app.apk"`
With single quotes, double quoutes and no quotes. Result:

```
    I/SHELL(1432): Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

    I/SHELL(1432): Options:
    I/SHELL(1432):   -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
    I/SHELL(1432):   -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
    I/SHELL(1432):   -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
    I/SHELL(1432):   -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd
    I/SHELL(1432):   -v, --version                 display version number and exit
    I/SHELL(1432):   -V                            display version code and exit. this is
    I/SHELL(1432):                                 used almost exclusively by Superuser.apk
```

Other commands like **ls** runs fine.

**How I can install an apk located in /mnt/sdcard?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
su -c "pm install /mnt/sdcard/app.apk" root
```

But i think, it doesn't work if you have no root your phone

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

```
    Process p;  
    try {  
            // Preform su to get root privledges  
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");   

            // Attempt to write a file to a root-only  
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());  
            os.writeBytes(**any command**+"\n");  

            // Close the terminal  
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
            os.flush();  
            try {  
                    p.waitFor();
                    if (p.exitValue() != 255) {  
                            // Sucess :-)
                    }  
                    else {  
                           // Fail
                    }  

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                    // Fail
            }  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
            // Fail
    }
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Also from this command are you able to install apk file from your application?

Comment: Yes. -> os.writeBytes("pm install app.apk\n");

Comment: @Ricmcm: I have tried your code. But I am getting "write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)" error in this line "os.writeBytes("pm install myapp.apk\n")". What may be the problem. Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: @Manoj I am having the same issue (Broken Pipe). Is there any good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a doubt that when you are executing a command its not a ADB Shell its your application's shell environment.

From code:  (If you want to do it by Intent then)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path+"/<application_name>.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the permissions..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: I need to install it on multiple devices remotely. I need to do it silently. I found the solution.